# How do you create new UserType in Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

I was looking on the user service and found a lovely method:

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/ae1b6d95b803f11594ec27a15674b0a6b0d41f5f/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/UserService.cs

```
public void SaveUserType(IUserType userType, bool raiseEvents = true)
```

It takes `IUserType`. The implementation which i can see on Github:

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/d50e49ad37fd5ca7bad2fd6e8fc994f3408ae70c/src/Umbraco.Core/Models/Membership/UserType.cs

is internal.

How do i create a new `UserType` programatically in Umbraco?

I have also tried:

```
Roles.Provider.CreateRole("Test User Type");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your own version of the class:

Make sure to add reference: `System.Runtime.Serialization`;

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class ProvisioningUserType : Entity, IUserType
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<string> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Instantiate this and use with the `SaveUserType` method

> If you are getting this error: String or binary data would be
>   truncated
>
> then you are probably using the wrong permission values. These seem to
>   work:

```
public class UserTypes
{
    public const string CultureAndHostNames = "I";//"Culture and Hostnames";
    public const string AuditTrail = "Z";//"Audit Trail";
    public const string BrowseNode = "F";//"Browse Node";
    public const string ChangeDocumentType = "7";//"Change Document Type";
    public const string Copy = "O";//"Copy";
    public const string Delete = "D";//"Delete";
    public const string Move = "M";//"Move";
    public const string Create = "C";//"Create";
    public const string PublicAccess = "P";//"Public access";
    public const string Publish = "U";//"Publish";
    public const string Permissions = "R";//"Permissions";
    public const string Rollback = "K";//"Rollback";
    public const string SendToTranslation = "5";//"Send To Translation";
    public const string Sort = "S";//"Sort";
    public const string SendToPublish = "H";//"Send To Publish";
    public const string Translate = "4";//"Translate";
    public const string Update = "A";//"Update";
    public const string UserGroupPermission = "œ";//"User Group Permissions";
}
```